# What is not found http exception in routecollection?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am beginner to laravel. I went through few tutorials and videos and now I am trying to build my application.

Inside the web.php of routes folder, I have following simple code to call the index function of ListController,

```
Route::get('/link','ListController@index');
```

And then inside my ListController.php, I just try to display the hello world output.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ListController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

But when i hit the url in address bar "http://localhost:8000/firstapp/public/link"
I am getting NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179: error

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Its to do with your app base. Ideally you should add your app alias to apache and rewrite the base so you can use `/firstapp/link` as your url directly. But a quick and dirty fix is to change your route  to ` Route::get('/firstapp/public/link"','ListController@index');`

Comment: @JasonJoslin I get FatalThrowableError in web.php line 25:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Comment: Yes the error explains it well, syntax error. If you use a decent IDE it will help you identify the error. I know Netbeans is a resource hog, but I find the code formatting plugins and syntax checking good.

Comment: It worked again but I dont know what was the exact mistake I did

Comment: Probably something as simple as hitting the page before you saved your changes. I do it too often haha.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `firstapp/public/link` in URL, so you need to route whole path like,

```
Route::get('/firstapp/public/link','ListController@index');‌
```

Comment: I get FatalThrowableError in web.php line 25:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Comment: Somewhere, you missed to place `;` or `}`. Check that your file has valid syntax.